# no CustomField named Event.IsVisibleInSelfService found - Managed Package

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, managed-package, permission-sets

Trying to upgrade the managed package from another Org getting bellow error.

`XXYY_Manager: In field: field - no CustomField named Event.IsVisibleInSelfService found`

XXYY_Manager is a Permission set. i dont find this field `IsVisibleInSelfService`  in the event/Activity Object. Can Any one help me on this

Previously I was able to deploy it to several orgs

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/101698.   Target org might not have legacy Self Service Portal, Customer Service Portal, or Partner Portal

Comment: I have seen a similar scenario. Can you clarify if you have Digital Experience enabled in the other org?

Comment: @user3214361 Following up to see if you have any inputs

Comment: I face the same deployment problem "In field: field - no CustomField named Event.IsVisibleInSelfService found". Did you find the field or a solution ?